# How do I setup TWRP on my SM-T295?

Tags: samsung, twrp, heimdall

I've tried almost every twrp.img I can find on the internet that supports my device (SM-T295, Android 11) yet I can't seem to get it to work. Every twrp recovery.img I try still results in the "Security check failed: RECOVERY.IMG" error. I do have an unlocked bootloader though.

**I've tried:**

1. Flashing an empty vbmeta
   -probably disabled AVB.
2. Downgrading to a less secure Android 9 bootloader.
   -Almost every .img was a success except the ABOOT.img which, after being succesfully flashed, displays the error: "SW REV CHECK FAILED" and two numbers I can't quite remember

Software Details:
SM-T295
T295XXS6WG2
Android 11

(I use heimdall-frontend for flashing btw)